# Find radius of circle with two known intersecting tangent points.

Tags: geometry

Consider the following circle. If I know only points A($x_1$, $y_1$) and point C ($x_2,y_2$). With no other given information is it possible to find the radius of this circle?
I tried the approach of finding the distance between $AB$ and $CB$ and equate them and got one equation with two unknown variables. Now I don't know how to use this information to find $AD$ or $CD$. Any hint or suggestion will be helpful. 
[image]

If we suppose that point $B$ is on $y-axis$ then instead of many solutions we can get one definite solution. I got one solution with using trig functions. Can anyone solve it without using $trigs$

Comment: There are several possible radius lengths for a circle that includes points A and C.

Comment: @Landuros yeah I realized that so what if this point B is on X or Y axis. so either x or y  will be zero

Comment: Then it is possible to determine the radius using some coordinate geometry.

Comment: You say that you only know points $A$ and $C$? Without $B$ or the tangent lines themselves, this isn’t enough information. Even knowing that $B$ lies on a coordinate axis isn’t enough—you’ve still got a degree of freedom left.

Answer (score 1):

Intersect the mediatrix of $AC$ with the axis $y$, to find $B$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AC$. Then

$$\frac{AD}{AM}=\frac{BA}{BM}$$ gives you the radius. (Or draw $AD$ perpendicularly to $BA$ by $A$.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have the cordinates of B (or another equivalent data), this is imposible. In deed finding the radius of the circle is equivalent to say that there is one circle that passes form $A$ and $C$ and intersecting tangent points witch is not true if you consider any point $ D$ from the mediator of $[A C]$ (and not its  middle) instead of your $D$.

Comment: Yeah I realized that so lets assume the point B is on y-axis.